# PHP submit form and stay on form with success message

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i have a MODAL which holds dynamic content coming from a DB via PHP echo.

This Modal is a form and when I click on submit it should stay in that Modal. At the moment i have a header(LOCATION:..) in the action PHP file. This header function push back to the original page and i lose my Session.

I want something like a silent submit with an success message within the MODAL. Not sure yet in how to accomplish.

Below is my code so far.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Add</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <?php foreach ($campaignHeader as $CampFormrow){?>
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Insert Data
          <?php echo "$CampFormrow[CAMPAIGN_DESCRIPTION]";?> / ID:
          <?php echo $_GET["ID"]; ?>
        </h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        /* Below is the FORM START */
        <form action="/includes/KPIinsert.inc.php" method="post" id="InsertKPIForm">
          <div class="form-group">
            <legend>Brand</legend>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="KPIbrand" value="Test" id="KPIvalue" placeholder="JAGUAR" readonly="readonly" style="width:50%;">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <legend>Nameplate</legend>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="KPInameplate" value="testItem" id="KPInameplate" placeholder="testItem" readonly="readonly" style="width:50%">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <legend>Campaign ID</legend>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="KPIcampaignID" value="<?php echo " $CampFormrow[CAMPAIGN_ID] ";?>" id="KPIcampaignID" placeholder="<?php echo " $CampFormrow[CAMPAIGN_ID] ";?>" readonly="readonly" style="width:50%">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <legend>KPI value</legend>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="KPIvalue" id="KPIvalue" placeholder="Numbers only">
          </div>
          <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend>Select Market for KPI</legend>
            <div class="form-check">
              <label class="form-check-label">
                <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="KPImarket" id="KPImarket" value="DE" checked> Germany
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <label class="form-check-label">
                <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="KPImarket" id="KPImarket" value="IT" checked> Italy
              </label>
            </div>

          </fieldset>
          <div class="form-group">
            <legend>Additional Information</legend>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="KPInotes" id="KPInotes" placeholder="Notes here">
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <div class="form-group">
              <button class="btn btn-secondary" id="KPIdataInsert" name="KPIdataInsert" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        Successfully transmitted
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php }?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The short answer is that you have to use AJAX for this.

Comment: Have a look at XMLHttpRequests

Comment: You could have a PHP method that adds script to page (if post data exist) that triggers the modal (forces the modal to open).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a Ajax call to Submit the Form.

Example:

```
<script>
    $("#InsertKPIForm").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/includes/KPIinsert.inc.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: forData,
            success: function(res){
                alert("Successfully Submitted the Form");
            },
            error: function(err){
                alert("Form Not Submitted. Try Again later !!!");
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Here, you will not be redirected to another Page...You will get the response on the Modal itself.

Comment: We should not answer overly broad questions.

Comment: @JayBlanchard, i have updated the code...previously i was just lookedup the Question, Not the answer...Your commented while i was editing the answer...
Hope your mentioned problem is solved with edited one.

Comment: Ajax works indeed. But now the values in the input fields stay. Any chance I can get them empty after the submit?

Comment: Yes...
Inside success function do like $("#InsertKPIForm").reset();

It should Work

Comment: jQuery does not have a `.reset()` function, JavaScript does. In order to use it correctly you would do this: `$('#InsertKPIForm')[0].reset()`

Comment: @JayBlanchard that did the trick. The other throughs an error.